# Adaptive Boosting - Visualize Tree

Tags: java, weka, adaboost

I'm using the **Weka api in Eclipse** for classification using **Adaptive Boosting** and **J48** as the base classifier.

I know that we can visualize tree if we are to use just the J48 algorithm alone as the classifier without boosting.

So in this case of using AdaBoost with J48 as the base classifier is it possible to visualize all those trees generated by the AdaBoost algorithm?

I have read the documentation for Weka but have'nt found anything that could help(May be I missed somethings?).

I can get the tree in this textual format, but I want it in a graphical format, like the one we get on weka on using j48 classifier

```
    public void somMethod(){
        AdaBoostM1 m1 = new AdaBoostM1();

        //setting the class for classification
        trainingData.setClassIndex(classIndex);

        //setting the base classifier
        m1.setClassifier(new J48());

        //setting number of iterations
        m1.setNumIterations(numIterations);

        //building the final classifier
        m1.buildClassifier(trainingData);

        System.out.println(m1);
    }
```

[image: Output (tree in textual format)]